# QGIS: ideas on how to show unsupported geometry data type

Tags: postgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am working on a university project and I need to visualize data from PostgreSQL. The data type is new, geometry with a time attached to it, which it is available because of extension in PostgreSQL.

I need to find a way to visualize this data in QGIS (create a plugin), and I couldn't find relevant information online. This blog post is similar to what I am trying to achieve, but using the data type mentioned before.
* https://anitagraser.com/2017/08/14/movement-data-in-gis-7-animated-trajectories-with-timemanager/

Does anyone here have ideas on how to approach?

Comment: What postgres extension is used?

Comment: @ndawson the extension is still in testing and not yet available to use for everyone. This is an example format of a point that has a time attached to it "Point(2 1)@2018-01-01 08:00:00)"

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to create a view which casts the custom data type to a standard PostGIS geometry